# Insert a base map with contour map via MATLAB

Tags: matlab, coordinates, matlab-figure, contour, matplotlib-basemap

I have created a contour map, with latitude, longitude and a value (X,Y,Z). I have used commands like `meshgrid` and it works. I would like to put a base map and paste the contour map I've created on the base map. Which command should I use in order to create it?

I would like to create a map like the example in the photo.

[image: map with colors and isolines]

Comment: Have you looked at the [Mapping Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/mapping.html)?

Comment: yes but I can't find the command it suits me better to solve my problem...